# Mocking struct argument

Tags: go

FULL DISCLOSURE: This is probably really dumb, but I'm new to Go and haven't used statically-typed languages in years.

I have a function that looks like this:

```
func Foo(bar *bar.BarStruct) {
  // do stuff with bar
}
```

In this example, bar is a third-party package and *bar.BarStruct is a pointer to a struct.

I would like to write a test for the Foo function while stubbing out bar.BarStruct struct. How would I stub out *bar.BarStruct?

In JavaScript for example, I would just do something like this

```
test('does a Foo', () => {
  const mockBarStruct = {
    someProp: 123
  }

  Foo(mockBarStruct)
  // rest of test
})
```

What's the equivalent way to stub a struct in Go?

Comment: "I would like to write a test for the Foo function" that is a good idea, "while stubbing out bar.BarStruct" this is not a good idea. Testing Foo is done by invoking Foo with a certain argument and afterward checking it did the right thing. Mocking is almost never the right approach to testing. In almost all cases a fake/stub is enough and you should concentrate on more different inputs.

Comment: Accept interfaces, return concretions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you had Foo take an interface instead of a struct pointer, the in tested you could pass a mock or fake struct that implements that interface.

There are some mocking libraries but because Golang doesn’t allow runtime type writing, they run compile-time and output code.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks, I had done that in a few places, but I'm working on existing code and would have to change a bunch of method signatures. Is there no other way other than passing in interfaces instead of structs? If that's the case, I wonder why people would ever pass in structs because of how hard it is to test.

Comment: That's an interesting comment about how maybe everything should be an interface. Go's type system is similar to "duck typing" (https://medium.com/@matryer/golang-advent-calendar-day-one-duck-typing-a513aaed544d) which often makes it easy to convert a struct parameter to an interface parameter after the fact. Also, many IDEs have tools that will help with this type of type re-writing code. It's part of the art of Go over the science to decide when an interface and when a struct is the best argument to a function.